# postgres ident authentication failed

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up django on a fresh Ubuntu VM.  I'm following the tutorials along until I get to this:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The Ubuntu user "postgres" has had its password set to 123456:

```
sudo su postgres -c passwd
```

Using pdadmin, I connect to the pg instance at localhost, go into Login Roles, right click on the user 'postgres' and set the password to 123456.  I then click OK and exit pgadmin3.

But, even after doing all this,

```
psql -U postgres -W
```

rejects the password I have given it.  Django also continues to give me the same error even though settings.py has been setup with the correct info.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This article and its comments might help:

[“FATAL: Ident authentication failed”, or how cool ideas get bad usage schemas](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/10/04/ident/)

Comment: I had to reload pg_hba.conf after changing it...e.g. while logged into postgres:  SELECT pg_reload_conf();

Answer (score 3):

change IPv4 local connections to **trust** in pg_hba.conf.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: This is allow ALL local users connect without passwords to Postgres. This is bad idea